# NLog File is not Generated in ASP.Net Core Web MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

I'm new developer trying to create a solution that has several projects in Visual Studio 2019 with C# language. I need to create one NLog.config file and used by all the other projects. So I create an **Infrastructure Layer Project** that has Nlog.Config file and I do all the configuration, within the  **Infrastructure Layer Project**

In **Nlog.Config file** I wrote

```
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="LogFile" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="LogRules" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="LogFile" />
 </rules>
```

I create a class named **ApplicationBase** with code

```
public class ApplicationBase
    {
        protected Logger Log { get; private set; }

        protected ApplicationBase(Type declaringType)
        {
            Log = LogManager.GetLogger(declaringType.FullName);
        }
    }
```

I create another class named **EmpVO** with a code

```
public class EmpVO : ApplicationBase
    {
        public EmpVO() : base(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)
        {
            Log.Info("Instance created");
        }
    }
```

I create another project named **presentation layer**, that is an Empty web ASP.net Core 3.0, with start.cs file

I wrote

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                EmpVO emp = new EmpVO();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
            });
        }
```

The solution working fine with no errors and built it with no errors. But cannot generate an initial NLog file.

So what should I do to make it generate the NLog and to have one single NLog file to be used by all other projects.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing all that painful manual work when you could just add NLog to the dependency injection container and forget completely about it? https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3

Comment: Well I need to have one single nlog for several projects in one solution

Comment: That doesn't change absolutely anything of what I mentioned

Comment: I think using NLog.Web.AspNetCore (see the linked tutorial by Camilo) is indeed better in this case (with the current info). But, I think it's also important to see here why the log file isn't created, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` attribute in the `<logger>` is a name filter. So currently you only route logs from the LogRules logger to you target.

Start otherwise with `name="*"`:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="LogFile" />
```

And if it's unclear what your logger name is, you could also log that with `${logger}`

See also [the docs for logger rules](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules)